# Suggested strategy for accessing the starting location in react-router onEnter hook

Tags: react-router, redux, react-router-redux

I am trying to implement an authentication/authorization strategy with react-router (using v2.x) via the `onEnter` hook. (also using redux and react-router-redux)

I think i am most of the way there, but there is a scenario where i am located in either an unprotected-or-authorized location, and i attempt a transition to a protected-and-unauthorized location where i want to "stay put", but when i hit the `onEnter` hook, the `nextState` argument is already at the unauthorized location and i am wanting to `replace` with the original starting location.

I am currently tinkering with saving my own history of locations in redux state to be able to have the starting location available, but it seems like there should be an easier way to accomplish the desired effect.

Any suggestions/guidance appreciated!